# Do i have to dispose a parameter in C#?

Tags: c#, memory-management, memory-leaks, emgucv

I currently use a NDA-library (non commercial) which has zero documentation and uses EMGU.
Here is a example for my Question:

```
public void example()
{
     Image<Gray,byte> exp = new Image<Gray,byte>(128,128);
     foo(exp);
     exp.Dispose();
}

public bool foo(Image<Gray,byte> bar)
{
     //magic here
     //bar.Dispose() ??
     return true;
}
```

When I pass an EMGU-Image from one function to another, do i have to call `.Dispose()` in the called function, too? Or is it sufficient to call it in the callee?

Comment: Good question, but it has already been answered at length. The standard rule of thumb is, if you *create* it, you're responsible for *disposing* it (unless there is an agreed-upon transfer of ownership). For more details, also look up how parameters are passed. Objects like this are passed by reference in C#, so you're not making a copy of the object.

Comment: Note also that you should use the `using` keyword to ensure that exp.Dispose() is called, even if an exception is thrown.

Comment: @CodyGray oh snap! But I swear I used the search multiple times. But maybe I just wasn't able to search it with the right words. Thanks for your answer (comment) and the Link!

Answer (score 0):

It's better to only call `Dispose()` once. However it should be ok to call it more than once, if the `Dispose()` method was written in the "normal fashion."